# UIWebView cannot redirect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm new to Objective-C.

I have made an application which redirects a string to a webView.  I want that webView should load wikipedia and should search the contents present in that string.

I have written like this...

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page/search=%@",str1];
//[urlString stringBy];
NSLog(@"url   %@",urlString);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: seems like problem with outlet.

Comment: Have you added the webview to a view shown on the screen?

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

// Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

// URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Good luck

Comment: How does it relate to a question?

Comment: Kindly write code between code tags-->  `  . These characters should be to the left of the '1' key on your keyboard. Thanks and Welcome to SO:)
e.g. `code goes here`

Comment: thanks iHunter but actually i want my string to be directly redirected to the wikipedia and wikipedia will search the contents of that string....